# MySQL server wont' start. Reason: Internal error

Tags: mysql

The very vague error message

**Reason: Internal error**

I've had this happen before, and it usually fixes itself after I restart my machine, but after the 4th time now it still is showing the error :(

Update: Found my.cnf file, details below:

```
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 128M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M
thread_concurrency = 4
innodb = on
innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:512M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
"my.cnf" [readonly] 67L, 1336C
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
default-storage-engine = innodb
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
user = mysql
symbolic-links = 0
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
max_length_for_sort_data = 8388608
max_sort_length = 8388608
group_concat_max_len = 32M

net_buffer_length = 1M
max_connections = 32768
back_log = 32768

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
open-files-limit = 8192

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 32M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash
database = whoat
#safe-updates
[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Any idea what is going on? Here is the server log

[image]

---

I was able to start SQL from MySQL Workbench, would like to know how I breached the max open file limit however

[image]

Comment: The server **did** start at 09:33, and then at 15:15 there was a "normal shutdown". Apparently the problem is not that it doesn't start, it is that *something stops it after a few hours*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this issue before, I'm not sure if it's the same problem considering you are only experiencing a warning but try increasing the max open file size. I

You can test the max open files using the code below

```
    SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open%'
```

If it's lower than what you are using you might want to edit/create the my.cnf file. Just make sure the code below is placed in the file.

```
    open_files_limit = *int amount of files you would like to increase to *
```

then restart

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

If you show variables again, you should see the amount you put in.

I hope that helps. Worked for me.

Comment: Hi where do you run that command `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'open%'`? I can't run anything in MySQL workbench at the moment cause I can't start the server. Also I see that my `open-files-limit = 8192` if that helps?

Comment: Just expand the out to 40000 to be safe with the code above. Should help

Comment: I think this is the answer, I was able to start MySQL again by starting it from Workbench, but still got a warning about max open files. Posting a screenshot in my answer

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me before and while there's nothing in the logs to really point you in the right direction the first place to start is in the MySQL's configuration file (*On a Mac, I believe it is called **my.cnf** and it is found in **/etc***).

You may have made some adjustments or tweaks that it doesn't agree with. Going a bit overboard with certain values (max_open_files for example you're requesting 33802 out of the maximum of 8192, this could be the culprit) can lead to this scenario where MySQL just *doesn't* want to kick off.

Take a look inside your conf file and try editing the values to be your defaults. You may be able to find example files here: **/usr/local/mysql/support-files/**

Once you fix it and wish to tweak, just tweak one at a time and start MySQL to confirm it can run with that desired change. It's a little more time consuming but it helps avoid scenarios like this in the future.

Comment: thanks! I added the details to my file above, not really sure what to mess with first, let me know if anything stands out?

Comment: The copy/paste isn't complete. You're missing some of it.
Take a look at your default files and compare the diffs.

Your MySQL log makes reference to **max_open_files**. That'd be my first stop.

Comment: ah thanks :) just pasted the full cnf file above... I'm playing around with the variables right now, so far nothing yet